# Remote Desktop cannot connect to the remote windows 8 computer from windows 7

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have computer with installed windows 8 pro at home. This computer plugged in to router via LAN cable. I configured remote desktop on this computer: System Properties -> Remote -> Allow remote connections to this computer ("Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication" unchecked). I also configured router to forward the Remote Desktop port (3389) from the Internet IP address of router to the Local IP of my host. I checked forwarding at http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ - Port 3389 is open.

I can connect to windows 8 pc from my mobile phone (windows phone 7.8, via [RemoteDesktop](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/remotedesktop/e2af408b-555a-e011-854c-00237de2db9e) application). But it is not convenient.

I can't connect to home pc from work (Windows 7 Pro). I have the following error:

"Remote desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:
1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network
Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled. "

I can connect to home pc from work via mobile phone, but from work pc I get error. Is on work PC any other configurations to connect to win 8?

UPD: I have to use proxy server at work, is it might cause problems?

Comment: When you connect from work via mobile phone do you use work wireless or 3G/4G? This may answer why it works on your phone all the time - it's using your 3G/4G data allowance. When using work computer do you know if your work block outbound connections to port 3389? - my work do.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and scratched my head over it for ages. It turned out that I use Kaspersky anti-virus and by default the Kaspersky firewall silently blocks Remote Desktop connections.

Check your AV/firewall settings are ok on your work PC ....

Comment: Firewall settings are ok. I can connect to pc from mobile phone using the 3G connection. So, port 3389 is enabled.

Comment: I mean your outgoing firewall restrictions on your work PC.

Comment: It looks like that outgoing tcp 3389 is enabled. I checked it in Windows Firewall -> Advanced settings. I also added outbound rule that allow 3389 tcp port. But I have the same error.

Comment: Another quick way to check is to temporarily disable your firewall on your work PC.

Comment: Unfortunately some settings are managed by my system administrator and I can't disable my firewall

Comment: Make sure you used the correct method to enable Remote Desktop on your firewall then - not just by port, but choose the option "Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall" and scroll down to Remote Desktop and make sure it's checked.

Comment: Yes, I found it, I have 2 checked "Remote Desktop" - 1) "Remote Desktop" checked for Domain, Home/Work()Private, Public, Group Policy - Yes; 2) "Remote Desktop" checked for Domain, Home/Work()Private, Public, Group Policy - No;

Answer (score 0):

Try using remote support tools such as [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/), [GoSupportNow](http://www.gosupportnow.com/), [GoToMyPC](http://www.gotomypc.com) etc. in order to remotely access Windows 8 computer from Windows 7. Check if they work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite certain this has nothing to do with Windows 7 -> Windows 8. Just the other day I was able to do this.

The nature of that error message indicates the computer that initiated the session was never able to reach or never got a response from the target computer.

This could have happened if the remote address, ip address, etc is incorrect. Firewall/AV settings, proxys would also do this.

Additionally, all the 'pre-setup' configuration you did sounds correct... except for the proxy and or firewall settings and infos.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the security settings.  What I mean by this is how the authentication is being passed in the RDP session.  I would lower it all the way down and see if that works. If it does, you can increase it until it doesn't work.  Make sure the settings are the same on both ends.  I had this issue once before and the authentication was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to use a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) at work as you say in the last line.

When you use a proxy for connecting to Internet the computer usually *don't have* direct/NAT access to Internet, instead programs *designed* to use a proxy (mostly browsers) connect to the proxy server, then the proxy server retrieves the requested content from Internet (or from a local cache in some cases) and pass it back to your computer.

Most of the time proxies are used for web browsing (and maybe for email), but a lot of programs that use other protocols, including Remote Desktop, needs a direct or NAT connection to Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 uses RDP version 8.0. This is supported by Windows 7 (as a client PC) but only with the correct updates installed see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/2592687/remote-desktop-protocol-rdp-8-0-update-for-windows-7-and-windows-serve.

Comment: The download link is not currently working(Error 404)